# How to use user input as the function for a numeric integration algorithm?

Tags: python, math, numerical-methods, numerical-integration, calculus

I found an algorithm that calculates the area under the curve of a function using Riemann's sum, also known as approximation by rectangles. However, i have to change the function inside the algorithm everytime i want to calculate a different function. In the code below, the algorithm is set to calculate the area under the curve of `x**2`.

```
# Calcuate the area under a curve
#
# Example Function y = x^2
#
# This program integrates the function from x1 to x2
# x2 must be greater than x1, otherwise the program will print an error message.
#
x1 = float(input(’x1=’))
x2 = float (input(’x2=’))
if x1 > x2:
    print(’The calculated area will be negative’)
# Compute delta_x for the integration interval
#
delta_x = ((x2-x1)/1000)
j = abs ((x2-x1)/delta_x)
i = int (j)
print(’i =’, i)
# initialize
n=0
A= 0.0
x = x1
# Begin Numerical Integration
while n < i:
    delta_A = x**2 * delta_x
    x = x + delta_x
    A = A + delta_A
    n = n+1
print(’Area Under the Curve =’, A)
```

I've tried asking user to input a function like, lets say `exp((x** 2)-x) * sin(x**3)` from `x1 = 1` to `x2 = 2.5`, but it doesnt work, it displays an error message of invalid syntax. Tried using eval(input(...)) method and it calculated, but it gave the wrong answer (1.2612...). The correct answer for this problem is 2.397...

It is an inconvenience having to rewrite the function in the algorithm, it is not practical to the user.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Show the code that does not work. Are you positive that the code you use to integrate is correct? Note that scipy package has ready made and tested integration functions that are more accurate.

Comment: You can also use sympy parsing: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html

Comment: Thanks @Tarik for your suggestion on using SciPy, i didnt know about it. It will be very useful to me.

Comment: Also have a look at sympy.

Answer (score 4):

As @Tarik commented, check your code's logic first.

Then Try [`eval()`](https://realpython.com/python-eval-function/), an example could be:

```
from math import exp,sin


def integration(func_string, x1, x2):
    reverse = 0
    if x1 > x2:
        print('The calculated area will be negative')
        reverse = 1
        x1, x2 = x2, x1

    delta_x = (x2 - x1) / 1000
    # initialize
    A = 0.0
    x = x1

    while x <= x2:
        delta_A = eval(func_string) * delta_x
        x = x + delta_x
        A = A + delta_A
    if reverse == 1:
        A = -A
    print('Area under the curve', A)


if __name__=='__main__':
    x1 = float(input('x1='))
    x2 = float(input('x2='))
    integration('exp((x** 2)-x) * sin(x**3)', x1, x2)
```

The example I/O:

```
x1=1
x2=2.5
Area under the curve 2.395500858985482
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I will go with what Tarik suggested, the SciPy. I didnt know about that SciPy thing, it is very very useful for calculus, engineering and science. I will stick with it's documentation, im sure it will be very helpful. Thanks again.